# How detect user touch interaction in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my activity there are `ActionBar,ListView,ContextMenu,Menu`.

I wanted to capture the user interaction with my activity(means when ever user touch in my activity i wanted to show a toast).I use this

```
@Override
    public void onUserInteraction() 
    {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This method working with in screen but problem with this method its not working with

`Menus,ContextMenu(ListView)`.

**Working Scenario**:-
1-This is working first time when i touch the screen Every where in activity (ActionBar,ListView).

2-After clicking the `Menus` first time this method is calling and if the `Menu` is related to activity (if i want to go on next activity ) it is working fine but there is a `Menu` `REFRESH` in same activity ,i do not know why this method not calling on clicking on `REFRESH`.

3- The same problem with `ContextMenu` (comes after long press on `ListView`)

I tried `GestureDetecter` also.

**There is any particular method or anything in android ,which can detect the user touch every time in menus,contextmenu,list,screen or every where.**

Lots of Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can override dispatchTouchEvent() in your Activity to get the result you want

something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
  //do something
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```

[See the activity docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) for more

Also I think it is worth noting that your users may find it quite annoying if you are displaying a toast any time they touch anything on the screen.