# Is there any way to detect user interaction in fragments like we have default method in an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have gone through this  [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29), and [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150805/how-detect-user-touch-interaction-in-android) ,[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android) . this works fine with the activities but i want this functionality in fragment. I have timer in this fragments that i want to stop for interval when there is interaction with this fragment.

Comment: what do you mean by `interaction with this fragment`. put your code.

Comment: @maddy .. "interaction with this fragment" means if the user touched the screen , press the button in layout, scrolled the view......etc. i dont think there is need of code regarding this , because i tried this with activity and mentioned in the links, i just want to know is there any way to implements this in fragment. Any suggestions , most welcome.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267322/detecting-user-activity-in-android). it may be help you.